# requests.get crashes on certain urls

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.whosampled.com/search/?q=marvin+gaye')`
```

This returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Downloads\RealisticMellowProfile\Python\New folder\Term project demo.py", line 8, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://www.whosampled.com/search/?q=marvin+gaye')
  File "c:\users\thoma\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\thoma\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\thoma\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\users\thoma\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\thoma\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the user agent so the server does not close the connection:

```
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

r = requests.get('https://www.whosampled.com/search/?q=marvin+gaye', headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

The url is broken (or the server serving this url)

Try to get it with

```
wget https://www.whosampled.com/search/?q=marvin+gaye
```

or with

```
curl https://www.whosampled.com/search/?q=marvin+gaye
```

Use try / except to handle such situations. 
However you wnat be able to gat data from it (same as with wget or curl)

import requests

```
try:
    r = requests.get('https://www.whosampled.com/search/?q=marvin+gaye')`
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print("can't get data from this server")
    r = None

if r is not None:
    # handle succesful request
else:
    # handler error situation
```